# File not found when I try to download a .csv file from remote server to local browser

Tags: java, html, servlets, download, remote-server

I have a remote Linux server (Debian 9.2) with Tomcat 9. I loaded a web app on the server that generates a .csv file, the user can connect to the server and download it.
When the program runs on the localhost, it works well, however, when it runs on the remote server, the browser says: `file not found`

Here is my code:

```
private void writeFile(String nomeFile, String content, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

     response.setContentType("text/csv");
     response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+nomeFile);


    String filename=nomeFile;
     try {
     File file = new File(filename);


     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     bw.write(content);
     bw.flush();
     bw.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }


     // This should send the file to browser
     ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int length;
     while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
     in.close();
     out.flush();



}
```

I'm trying to debug this, but I do not know where the error could be. The servlet that implements the code runs fine on localhost. Why does it fail on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same code on local and remote machine and it works on one and does not work on the other it means one of 2 things:

1) localhost configuration of Tomcat might be different vs remote host
    - this might cause Tomcat to search "different" folder for file etc. OR
2) file is present only localhost and is not present on the remote host.

Comment: I create the file inside the server, then i transfer it to browser

Answer (score 0):

You can see in DevTools into your Browser on Network tab what is request string to remote server to get file and check it.
Also check your context on the remote server. It may be different with your localhost when you deploy project.
Type where you put csv file and path.